# How to define how much CPU to use in SFML game?

Tags: c++, cpu, sfml, cpu-usage

I've made a game but I don't know if the game will work the same way in other devices. For example if the CPU of a computer is high will the player and enemies move faster? If so, is there a way to define CPU usage available in SFML? The way the player and enemies move in my program is to : 
1-Check if the key is pressed 
2-If so : move(x,y); Or is there a way to get the CPU to do some operations in the move function. 
Thank you!

Comment: [Frame independent movement](https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=frame+independent+movement&gws_rd=cr&ei=N_6HV4OsF4myUYWgv9AF&fg=1). I recommend reading [this](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson32/index.php), though it's about SDL, you'll understand what's going on

Comment: Thanks fo the link!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are worried about the physics of your game being affected by the game's framerate. Your intuition is serving you well! This is a significant problem, and one you'll want to address if you want your game to feel professional.

According to Glenn Fiedler in his [Gaffer on Games](http://gafferongames.com/) article ['Fix Your Timestep!'](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/)

> [A game loop that handles time improperly can make] the behavior of your physics simulation [depend] on the delta time you pass in. The effect could be subtle as your game having a slightly different “feel” depending on framerate or it could be as extreme as your spring simulation exploding to infinity, fast moving objects tunneling through walls and the player falling through the floor!

Logic dictates that you must detach the dependencies of your update from the time it takes to draw a frame. A simple solution is to:

- Pick an amount of time which can be safely processed (your timestep)
- Add the time passed every frame into an accumulated pool of time
- Process the time passed in safe chunks

In pseudocode:

```
time_pool = 0;
timestep = 0.01; //or whatever is safe for you!
old_time = get_current_time();

while (!closed) {
    new_time = get_current_time();
    time_pool += new_time - old_time;
    old_time = new_time;

    handle_input();
    while (time_pool > timestep)
    {
        consume_time(timestep); //update your gamestate
        time_pool -= timestep;
    }
    //note: leftover time is not lost, and will be left in time_pool
    render();
}
```

It is worth noting that this method has its own problem:  *future frames have to consume the time produced by calls to `consume_time`*. If a call to `consume_time` takes too long, the time produced might require two calls be made next frame - then four - then eight - and so on. If you use this method, you will have to make sure `consume_time` is very efficient, and even then it would be best to have a contingency plan.

For a more thorough treatment I encourage you to read the linked article.